# How to set my span text vertical align and next to my image?

Tags: html, css

**Css**

```
.section_header {
    background-color: gray;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    display: table;
}

.section_header span {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:#740000;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.eventPic {
    width:20%;
    border:1px red solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="section_header">
    <span>
        <img src="image/bt_event.png" class="eventPic">
    </span>
    <span>服務說明</span>
</div>
```

I've set a table-cell to make my content vertical-align of div area.
Now, there is some spacing between my icon and text.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59z5bcu0/).

How can I solve it?
What I want is both icon and text vertical-align of this div and text is right next to icon.

Comment: why don't you just use width on the icon-span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `width` in both `span` and use `max-width` intend of `width` of image `eventPic` class named.

```css
.section_header {
  background-color: gray;
  width:100%;
  height:5em;
  display: table;
}

.section_header span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color:#740000;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.eventPic {
  /*width:20%;*/
  max-width:100%;
  border:1px red solid;
 }

.section_header span:nth-child(1){
  width:4%
}
  
.section_header span:nth-child(2){
  width:96%
}
```

```html
<div class="section_header">
        <span><img src="image/bt_event.png" class="eventPic"></span>
          <span>服務說明</span>
      </div>
```